# WPF ListBox Scroll to the bottom

Tags: wpf, scroll, listbox-control

I am using ObservableCollection as an ItemSource for my listBox component:

But the behavior of the control is not proper as for me. The matter I have scroll down to ths first occurence in my collection, but not last.

The sample list is: 1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,22,33,1

When you enetr last 1 you component scroll up to first 1 :). This not what I am wating for.

Please advise. Here a code of component:

```
public class MyListBox : ListBox
{
    protected override void OnItemsChanged(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnItemsChanged(e);
        if (Items.Count > 0)
        {
            var item = Items[Items.Count - 1];
            UpdateLayout();
            ScrollIntoView(item);
            UpdateLayout();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You have and ObservableCollection<string>?  If your last item is 33 does it work?   If so what is is doing is an equal comparison on the ListItems.  Try List<string> as it may behave differently.  If not then you need to bind to a custom class where you implement GetHashCode and overide Equals so th first 1 does not Equal the last     1.

Comment: Yes if 33 this works well because there is no 33 in collection before. I have to use ObservableCollection to meet changes of the data source. Its pity to bind to Custom class at all :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry but it needs to be a class as a List or OC is going to really do a value comparison.  So you need to make identical values unique.  I test this out and it works.

```
     <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
        <ListBox x:Name="lbStringList" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UniqueStringList}" DisplayMemberPath="Str" Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="56" />
     </StackPanel>


    private List<UniqueString> uniqueStringList = new List<UniqueString>() 
            {                   
                new UniqueString("zero",0),
                new UniqueString("one",1),
                new UniqueString("two",2),
                new UniqueString("three",3),
                new UniqueString("four",4),
                new UniqueString("five",5),
                new UniqueString("six",6),
                new UniqueString("seven",7),
                new UniqueString("zero",8)
            }; 

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    public List<string> StringList { get { return new List<string>() { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "one" }; } }
    public List<UniqueString> UniqueStringList 
    { 
        get 
        {
            return uniqueStringList;
        } 
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sender.GetHashCode());
        lbStringList.ScrollIntoView(lbStringList.Items[8]);

    }
    public class UniqueString
    {
        private Int32 id;
        public string Str { get; private set; }
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            UniqueString item = (UniqueString)obj;
            return item.id == id;
        }
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return id;
        }

        public UniqueString(string str, Int32 _id) { Str = str; id = _id; }
    }
```

Comment: Looks good. But not bad to use dateStamp instead of int ID to avoid unecessary parameter.

Comment: Thing is hash has to be Int32.  So if you can pass unique Int32 you are going to get a little faster code.  And I am pretty sure you have to overide GetHashCode if you are going to override Equals but I am not sure.  I am one of those make it go fast people.